# iOS storyboard - Disable selection on tabbarcontroller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

do you know how can i disable tabbar item buttons on storyboard? I want to disable all buttons when certain criteria where made, (eg. invalid user name), waiting for your advice guys, thanks.